# Jersey REST service not consuming JSON

Tags: rest, jersey, response, jersey-client

I have a REST service and client. I am trying to invoke this service to consume a JSON directly and convert it to the object I need. But it's not working. I am getting the following error: A message body reader for Java class com.a.b.c.D, and Java type class com.a.b.c.D, and MIME media type application/json was not found.

Service:

```
@Path("/getListPrice")
public class ListPriceService {

      @POST
      @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
      @Type(PricingObject.class)
      public Response search(PricingObject pricingObject, @Context final HttpHeaders headers) {
              .........
              return Response.ok().entity(pricingObject).build();
      }
}
```

Client:

```
WebResource webResource = client.resource(url);               
ClientResponse response = webResource.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                          .type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE)
                          .post(ClientResponse.class, pricingObjectRequest);

if (response.getStatus() != 200) {
   throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : " + response.getStatus());
}
```

Can someone tell me what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A message body reader for Java class com.a.b.c.D, and Java type class com.a.b.c.D, and MIME media type application/json was not found

You didn't say if you are getting a server side exception or a client side exception. If the former, you either don't have a provider for JSON, or you have one but haven't configure it.

Here is the provider

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey1-version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the web.xml configuration

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

If it's a client side exception, I would assume you have the above dependency. Then just configure it with the client

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
config.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
Client client = Client.create(config);
```

Comment: I have added the changes you mentioned to my web.xml and also to my client, but still I get the same issue.

Comment: Is this a server side problem? Is this where you are getting the exception? If so, show your web.xml

Comment: I figured the issue, the init-param was not added correctly and also had to add this <init-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.resourceConfigClass</param-name>
   <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.core.PackagesResourceConfig</param-value>
  </init-param>

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure Jersey to use handle Json -> Object mapping.  With Jersey 1 you need to add a json provider into your dependencies, e.g.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
    <version>1.17.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Okay, where do I do this? I am using Jersey 1.17.1 maven dependency.

Comment: I've updated the answer to give a maven example with the version you're using

Comment: I already had this dependency, I am still getting the same issue, even tried the below answer but no luck.

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your resource class as below

```
  /**<code>
     * {
     * "id"=1,
     * "name="priceitem1"
     * }
     * </code>

    **/
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response search(PricingObject pricingObject) {
        JSONArray jsarray=new JSONArray();
        jsarray.put(pricingObject);
        return Response.ok().entity(jsarray.toString()).build();
    }
```

The data whci is in between the  `tags are the json data that will come from the client.`

you can configure your bean class as below

```
public class PricingObject {
@XmlElement(name="id")
private int id;
@XmlElement(name="name")
private String name;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

The @xmlelement will bind the json keys with your bean class variables.